# Using some dynamic forms related to the same class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

**Symfony 2.3**

I'm embedding some `Form`s to be able to change each user property related to permissions. I've created an `UserAdminType` which is displayed for each user in the same page:

```
<?php

namespace Msalsas\UserAdminBundle\Form;

use Msalsas\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Msalsas\UserBundle\Entity\ExtendedUser;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class UserAdminType extends AbstractType
{
private $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->extendedUser = new ExtendedUser($this->user);
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $extendedUser = $this->extendedUser;

    $builder
        ->add('extendedRole',
            'choice', array('choices' => array(
                $extendedUser::ROLE_1 => "Role 1",
                $extendedUser::ROLE_2 => "Role 2",
                $extendedUser::ROLE_3 => "Role 3",
             ),
            'label' => $this->user->getUsername()
        ))
        ->add('Change roles for '.$this->user->getUsername(), 'submit')
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $data = $event->getData();

            if( ! $form->getClickedButton('Change roles for '.$this->user->getUsername()) )
            {
                  // Here I should avoid submitting the form 
            }

        }
    );

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Msalsas\UserBundle\Entity\ExtendedUser',
        'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                return null;
            }
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'extendedUserRoleForm';
}
}
```

The problem is that when I submit one of those forms, all other forms are also submitted, returning an error, because the `extendedUser` uses a constructor to initialize the object with the `User` as parameter:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Msalsas\UserBundle\Entity\ExtendedUser::__construct() must be an instance of Msalsas\UserBundle\Entity\User, none given, called in .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php on line 140 and defined

I've also tried to set the `empty_data` with a new default `ExtendedUser`:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Msalsas\UserBundle\Entity\ExtendedUser',
        'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                return $this->extendedUser;                    
            }
    ));
}
```

Now, when submitting the form, the new entity is persisted, but the other forms are still submitted, and returning an error: `This form should not contain extra fields.` This seems to be due to the duplicated property name (`extendedRole`).

How could I avoid the other forms to be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561424/multiple-forms-of-same-type-symfony-2#answer-10563279).

Each Form must have different name. So I've added a `$name` property, and assigned it in the constructor:

```
private $user;
private $name = 'default_name_';
private $extendedUser;

public function __construct(User $user, $formName)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->extendedUser = new ExtendedUser($this->user);
    $this->name = $this->name.$formName;
}

//... (No event required)

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

The `$formName` parameter is relative to the current user. In this way, only the "clicked" form is submitted. Wish it helps.