# symfony2 multiple form same type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to use the same formType several times in the same page, 
so in my Controller i have something like:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new updateSortieForm(), $sortie);
return $this->render('vue.html.twig,array('form'=>$form));
```

in my vue, i have loop which is supposed to render this form following a simple condition!

```
{% if sortie.dateretoueffective == null %}{
    {{ form(form,{'action':path('update_sortie',{'idSortie':sortie.idSortie}) })}}}
{% endif %}
```

the problem is that i need to instantiate this form multiple times, i've already tried this [method:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561424/multiple-forms-of-same-type-symfony-2)
it doesn't work, or maybe i'm doing something wrong, as i'm new to Symfony!

my form class is pretty simple:

```
class updateSortieForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        $builder->add('dateRetouEffective','date',array('label'=>false))

            ->add('MAJ','submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'alfarabiBundle_AlfarabiAppBundle_updateSortie';    }


}
```

Comment: You have to add a `constructor` method that take the form name as parameter to differentiate the two forms

Comment: I've already tried that! doesn't work!

Comment: try to add an attribute `name` in your `updateSortieForm` class then `$form1 = new updateSortieForm();`  `$form1->setName('form1');` for your instantiation `$this->createForm($form1, $sortie);` and do the same thing to form2

Comment: the forms are instantiated dynamically through a loop(in the vue), and only the first one is rendered.. i'm gonna edit my initial post with more details!

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html I'm not sure but I think this can help you..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't how others do this, but I solved it by custom TwigExtension. So, I created a TwigExtension, injected `request_stack`and `form.factory` services, declared a functon as `add_to_cart` and its method, created form with `createNamed` method of FormFactory service:

Custom TwigExtension:

```
...

public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('add_to_cart', [$this, 'getAddToCart']),
    ];
}

public function getAddToCart(User $user, Product $product)
{
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

    ...     

    $form = $this->formFactory->createNamed('add_to_cart_' . $product->getId(), 'sl_web_product_add_to_cart', null, [
        'action' => $this->router->generate($request->attributes->get('_route'), $request->attributes->get('_route_params'))
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        // some code here

        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'MESSAGE');

        $response = new Response();
        $response
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->headers->set('Location', $this->router->generate($request->attributes->get('_route'), $request->attributes->get('_route_params')))
        ;

        $response->send();
    }

    return $form->createView();
}
```

Usage in template:

```
{% set cart_form = add_to_cart(app.user, product) %}
```

I am not going to say that this is a good solution, but you can play around it and get an idea.

Comment: i've tried to understand your code, but i don't get how it's supposed to help in my case.